# Why the view controller not follow the window controller's appearance in segue "Modal"?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, storyboard, nswindowcontroller

there is a window controller connected to the view controller

when the menu item click I want to show that window as modal

[image]

after that the window is show, but I found that  the view controller not follow the window controller's appearance

[image]

also any window controller appearance is not working.. including content size, window title... etc

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Consider that you are presenting only the view controller and not any related window controller you define if you use `presentAsModalWindow(_ viewController: NSViewController)`

> The viewController is made the delegate and contentViewController of the window while it is shown

You could make the window customisations in viewWillAppear of your custom view controller

```
    override func viewWillAppear() {

    let closeButton = view.window?.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)
    closeButton?.isHidden = true

}
```

In `viewDidLoad` the window property will be still nil.

If you want to present your window controller do something like this triggered my your menu item.

```
    @IBAction func showMyWindowController(sender:NSMenuItem){

    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MyWindowController") as! NSWindowController

    windowController.showWindow(self)

}
```

Hope this helps